# customer dataflow advanced profile export retrieve field updated_at in xml action with map name doesn't work

Tags: customer, magento-1, export, dataflow

I am trying to export customers and want to export also the field `updated_at` which is in the table `customer_adress_entity`.

As in the advanced profile dataflow export there is no choice to choose that field I tried it with the xml actions possibility.

I added the following line

```
    <map name="updated_at"><![CDATA[updated_at]]></map>
```

but an empty value is the result. Even if there are values in the table.

Comment: May be this solution will help you <br>
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117286/export-all-customers-to-csv

Answer (score 1):

So from what I can see the customer dataflow will not export system fields. If you look into the class `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Convert/Parser/Customer.php` you can see the function `unparse`. This converts the data into the csv rows.

At the very beginning of this method it loads all the system fields as defined in the xml `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml` see node `admin->fieldsets->customer_dataflow`.

```
$systemFields = array();
foreach ($this->getFields() as $code=>$node) {
    if ($node->is('system')) {
        $systemFields[] = $code;
    }
}
```

Then during the parsing process the system will look through the customer data and process the data that it would like to export. The problem is that it will skip all data fields flagged as system.

```
if (in_array($field, $systemFields) || is_object($value)) {
    continue;
}
```

So you could do one of the following options:

1. Update the xml nodes so that `updated_at` is not a system field,
2. Update the `unparse` so that you can select some system fields to export,

Answer (score -2):

You need to alter the function load in

app/code/code/Mage/Customer/Model/Convert/Adapter/Customer.php

add below line after this $attrFilterArray ['created_at']                 = 'datetimeFromTo'; line

```
    $attrFilterArray ['updated_at']                 = 'datetimeFromTo';
```

And then add these :

```
    /*
     * Fixing date filter from and to
     */
    if ($var = $this->getVar('filter/updated_at/from')) {
        $this->setVar('filter/updated_at/from', $var . ' 00:00:00');
    }

    if ($var = $this->getVar('filter/updated_at/to')) {
        $this->setVar('filter/updated_at/to', $var . ' 23:59:59');
    }
```

So Basically just copy the created_at related code and change the created_at s to updated_at.

Then you can use that attribute to prepare your filter in Advanced Export profiles.

Cheers