# Export all customers to CSV

Tags: customer, export

I need to export the following customer information from our Magento site:

- First name
- Last name
- Email
- Store ID

Trying to do so via ***System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles*** just times out, despite several attempts at increasing various PHP memory and timeout limits on the server.

Please can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can create your php script, create one php file on root directory of your website and use following code.for ex: if file name is `exportCustomer.php` and your url is like **http://magentowebsite.com** then after placing this file in root you need to visit url like **http://magentowebsite.com/exportCustomer.php** then you will get a csv in your root directory with name as customers.csv

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
// Only for urls // Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init();
    Mage::app();   
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
ini_set('memory_limit','500M');
$customerCount = 0;
try{
    //configure the collection filters.
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('store_id');
    //Add a page size to the result set.
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    //discover how many page the result will be.
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;
    //This is the file to append the output to.
    $fp = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
    $addedKeys = false;
    do{
         //Tell the collection which page to load.
         $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
         $collection->load();
         foreach ($collection as $customer){
            //write the collection array as a CSV.
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Last name'] = $customerArray['lastname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Store ID'] = $customerArray['store_id'];
            if($addedKeys == false){
                $keys = array_keys($customerREquiredArray);
                fputcsv($fp, $keys);
                $addedKeys = true;
            }
            //var_dump($customerArray); echo "\n\n";
            fputcsv($fp, $customerREquiredArray);
            //fwrite($fp,print_r($customerArray,true) . chr(10) );
            $customerCount++;
         }
         $currentPage++;
         //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
         $collection->clear();
         //break; //DEBUG
         echo "Finished page $currentPage of $pages \n"; 
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
    fclose($fp);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //$response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    Mage::printException($e);
}
echo "Saved $customerCount customers to csv file \n";
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This works perfectly on Magento CE v1.9.2.4 but when I try it on v1.7.0.2 I get the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: lastname in exportCustomer.php on line 44`

Comment: i don't have knowledge of v1.7.0.2 but i think in this version field lastname not used edit the code and place this code `echo '<pre>';
   print_r($customerArray);
   exit;` on line no 43-46 you under foreach loop you will got to know what are the fields available their.

Comment: These are the fields are being displayed. lastname looks to be in the same format?
`Array
(
    [entity_id] => 
    [entity_type_id] => 
    [attribute_set_id] => 
    [website_id] => 
    [email] => 
    [group_id] => 
    [increment_id] => 
    [store_id] => 
    [created_at] => 
    [updated_at] => 
    [is_active] => 
    [disable_auto_group_change] => 
    [firstname] => 
    [lastname] => 
)`

Comment: can you pls come for  a chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40538/chat-with-user9539

Comment: comment code form line no 43-46 and  on line no 48 and 53creplace `$customerREquiredArray` with `$customerArray` and check if it works or not.

Comment: I've made those modifications and it appears to be working now. Is there a limit to the number of records that can be exported? The message in my browser ends with: `Finished page 304 of 3858 Finished page 305 of 3858 Fini` and only customers linked to store_id = 1 are being exported.

Comment: how many customers do you have ?

Comment: Roughly 190,000.

Comment: if you import all customers at a time then browser may gets hang. if you want to import more product at a time then you can changes `$collection->setPageSize(50);` at line no 29. if you are satisfied with the answer and if its working for you then you can accept and up vote it so that it will help others.

Comment: Cool! How to add CUSTOMER GROUP column? I added group_id and it works but only shows the "ID" and not the group name.

THANKS

Comment: please tell me how to display customer's order id in excel ?

Comment: Great script but I think it has performace issues. Running it on a 100k+ customers plateforme leads to a verry slow script, and time betweeb 2 "pages" increases a lot on each loop

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite app\code\local\Mage\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\Customer.php

And in line 200 modify code like this:

```
if ($addressAttribute) {
                    if ($addressAttribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
                        $optionIds   = explode(',', $value);
                        $optionTexts = array();
                        foreach ($optionIds as $optionId) {
                            $optionText             = $addressAttribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
                            $optionTexts[$optionId] = $optionText;
                        }
                        $addrAttributeMultiSelect[$address['parent_id']][$address->getId()][$column] = $optionTexts;
                    } elseif ($attrValues) {
                        $value = $attrValues[$value];
                    }
                }
```